How do I verify a reset token if the token is hashed in DB?
I need the user email using reset token. But its hashed in password_reset_tokens table in laravel 11.
Inside the users model I'm using inbuild function to override password reset token email template.
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
    {
        $resetLink = route('password.reset', ['token' => $token]);
        Mail::to($this->email)->send(new ResetPasswordMail($resetLink));
    }

It genrates the token like 7f13dbb4f7401fb0601a9ef3e53607e69e0bc511c51db66b6ec88e2719964e75
But its hashed in db.
How can  I get user info?

Why do you need to get the user info? By using the unique token mail will be sent to its respective user by default.You question is not clear. Even if you need user info you can get this by running a query to user model either based on email of token.

How can I get user email from token? I have token 7f13dbb4f7401fb0601a9ef3e53607e69e0bc511c51db66b6ec88e2719964e75.

In which table you have stored the token ?

password_reset_tokens its stored by laravel

try this DB::table('password_reset_tokens')->where('token',$token)->first();, I think it will work

No Token in HASH encrypted in db.

Expanding on @Subha comment.
Passwords, tokens and other sensitive data are always stored as their hashed variants, so you cannot get the exact token, you can only get the hashed variant.
So, I would recommend that you send the hashed token to the user and then, after the user visits the link with the token as a url query (domain.com?reset_token=7f13dbb4f7401fb0601a9ef3e53607e69e0bc511c51db66b6ec88e2719964e75), you check it $db_token == $inbound_token. That way, you do not worry about why is it hashed (as it is proper to hash sensitive data) and stored in the DB.
